# Find location of a value in a list using indices in another list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list: `[1,2,1]`, and another list that is guaranteed to be equal or longer in length: `[4,2,3,5]`, and these two lists are right aligned:

`[  1,2,1]`

`[4,2,3,5]`

I'd like to find the locations of all 1's in the first list, using the indices of the second list. In this example, the output should be `[1,3]`. Are there any neat ways without using loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you list need to find the difference in length between the two lists by simply subtracting the lengths. Then find all the indices of matching elements while adding the offset you just found. All together you'll have something like:

```py
offset = len(longer) - len(shorter)

offset_indices = [i + offset for i, value in enumerate(shorter) if value == 1]
```

Comment: Oh that right! Thanks josh!